# PHP/MYSQL - Confusing code block relating to additions to a mysql table via php

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

Would someone be able to enlighten me as to why when the following code block is run in my script, the error is triggered, but when the sql query is attempted directly via php myadmin, there are no problems.

There is a mysql connection running in the script.

```
// Generate a random key and add details to specials table
$email = $_POST['specials'];
$randomKey = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',12)),12);
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO specials SET
    id='',
    email='$email',
    verified='0',
    `key`='$randomKey',
    timestamp=NOW()
";
if (!mysqli_query($link, $sql))
{
    $error = 'Error adding email address to specials table.';
    include "$docRoot/html/main/error.html.php";
    exit();
}
```

I am quite sure that I have coded this correctly and before i go through a trail and error testing session, i thought thatone could have a brief look over this and tell me if they spot any obvious errors that may have eluded me.

Thanks for taking the time to read through this!

EDIT:

With the following code :

```
if (!mysqli_query($link, $sql12))
{
    echo mysqli_error();
    $error = 'Error adding email address to specials table.';
    include "$docRoot/html/main/error.html.php";
    exit();
}
```

I get the following output:

`Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /serveraddress/includes/inc/assistors/controllers.inc.php on line 161`

Comment: What's the error message returned by `mysqli_error()`?

Comment: Your code looks vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: try to echo $sql and then execute this query to phpmyadmin, it will show the error

Comment: @mathieu How would i check that?

Comment: @mark The email variable conversion is now the full process i use, I just added that so the code makes sense. Was there anything else you were referring to?

Comment: @BlackberryFan inside the IF do a `echo mysqli_error();` to render the error message. Show it in your post to indicate the error. Seems like the table has more columns which do not have any value specified here or any column that is numeric and you are sending a character value e.g. ID could be numeric but you are sending a blank string

Comment: @somath please see the edit in my post

Comment: @Moyed when I echo sql and excute the query through phpmyadmin it works...

Comment: @BlackberryFan Use `echo mysqli_error($link)` instead

Comment: @Mattieu Table 'compumvdsc_db1.specials' doesn't exist ­ but it does exit and it works fine when i execute through phpmyadmin? is specials a reserved word?

Comment: @MathieuImbert I also have a referance to this table in a query that is run before this and this is executed using the same table name

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but are you sure you are connected to the right database? Are you using only one database or more?

Comment: @MathieuImbert I am connected to the right database, and there is only one... A select statement on the specials table gives results, so i dont see why this is the case for my insert statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to see what exactly its returning

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: okay you have a point, the genterated key goes on forever... could you suggest a fix to this to make the random key only 12 chars long?

Comment: alright i have made it 12 chars long, but the error is still being triggered, the dump is as follows: "INSERT INTO specials SET id='', email='test@example.com', verified='0', `key`='bd0uU6zghZz8', timestamp=NOW()"

Comment: As per the documentation "mysqli_query" returns either true or false. so var_dump should return something like this "(boolean) True". U are doing something wrong. see the sample code i provided.

Comment: It states: bool(false) Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in etc, etc etc...

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if any of the fields are numeric by any chance? You are sending character data in each and as such that may be the reason for the SQL failing.

Since you mentioned that ID is an INT then please use the modified code below:

```
// Generate a random key and add details to specials table
$email = $_POST['specials'];
$randomKey = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',12)),12);
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO specials SET
    id=0,
    email='$email',
    verified=0,
    `key`='$randomKey',
    timestamp=NOW()
";
if (!mysqli_query($link, $sql))
{
    $error = 'Error adding email address to specials table.';
    include "$docRoot/html/main/error.html.php";
    exit();
}
```

`''` means a blank string and MySQL cannot successfully convert a blank string to a number of type INT from it and hence it was failing your SQL INSERT command. As such, you need to send either `0` or if your ID column allows `NULL` then you can also send `NULL`. But sending `''` will generate an error.

A point to note here is that the `'0'` sent by you to verified does not trigger the error as `'0'` successfully converts to `0` and hence MySQL does not have an issue with that.

The error was being generated as you were trying to save `''` i.e. a blank string to the ID column.

Comment: the fields are varchar, int or timestamp (the varchar i am using for the email and key fields)

Comment: @BlackberryFan I modified my answer with the correct command you need to send.